# Disable in game connection and allow character creation azerothcore

Tags: azerothcore

In [AzerothCore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk), how I can allow only character creations and disable in-game character connections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to touch the code, you could implement a mysql trigger that anytime a new character is created in the `characters` table, inserts a row in the `character_banned` table with `active` = 1

http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/character_banned

EXAMPLE:

```
delimiter #
create trigger ban_after_ins after insert on characters
for each row
begin
  insert into character_banned values (new.guid, 0, 0 , 'system', 'custom', 1);
end#
```

Comment: Ah yes, I had already thought of this, however the process is not automatic and would force to put everything manually, wouldn't there be an automatic way to block all connections?

Comment: triggers are automatic, I've added an example in my answere.

Comment: nice creative method